# Como devolver dos o mas selects mediante un procedimiento almacenado y como recibirlos en un dataset usando c#

Tags: c#, stored-procedure, sql-server-2008, dataset

Resulta que tengo un procedimiento almacenado donde devuelvo dos selects, simple y llanamente como hacer un `SELECT * FROM [NombreTabla]` , uno debajo del otro.

Yo desde C# lo que hago es recibirlo con un DataSet de la siguiente manera:

```
  var result = await db.SqlProcedure<DataSet>("Procedimiento").ToListAsync();
```

`result` me devuelve una lista con dos elementos, cada elemento se ve asi:

```
System.Data.DataSet
```

Dentro de cada uno tengo muchas propiedades, pero hay una en especial que es la que me atañe: `Tables`.

Dentro de cada uno hay un `Count` que siempre es igual a 0 y un `ResultView()` que me dice que la enumeracion no produjo ningún resultado, y es aqui donde deberia poder ver ambos selects.

Comment: Que te lleva a devolver el resultado de dos `select` diferentes  en el mismo procedimiento almacenado? No le veo ninguna utilidad, es por experimentación o hay alguna razón útil que se me escapa?

Comment: Dicho lo cual,[esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27543775/579895) es posible que sea lo que buscas. Pero aconsejaría no hacerlo así la verdad.

Comment: @Pikoh De hecho tiene mucha utilidad; surge la necesidad de pintar dos tablas en una vista, dos selects diferentes pero el mismo parametro de busqueda. Hacer otro procedimiento para esto? Eso si que no tendria utilidad y no seria para nada optimo.

Comment: Bueno, obviamente es opinable. Yo para empezar, no crearía un procedimiento almacenado para un simple select. Pero dejando eso aparte, yo si preferiría dos consultas, o dos procedimientos, antes que hacerlo asi :)

Comment: desgraciadamente, opino igual que @Pikoh.. es mas, si tu SP devuelve un berenjenal, donde no sabes que es cada cosa, suena raro. No vaya a ser que mañana cambien un campo...

Comment: que es db ? estas seguro que se usa con dataset, porque para mi ese SqlProcedure esta pensado para mapear contra uan entidad, o sea una clase que definas y no un dataset